# How to show Home Page link in Wordpress Menu and how to add an icon to this?

Tags: menus, homepage, icon

I tried with this code:

```
function home_page_menu_args( $args ) {
$args['show_home'] = true;
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'home_page_menu_args' );
```

but gives me this error: `Error 404 - Not Found`

I would like that when I click on "Home Page" menu appears the recent posts.
And I would like to place an **icon** instead of "Home Page" writing.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling the menu in your template? In terms of the icon you can do that using CSS so it's not strictly WordPress related. You can get answers to that on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @sanchothefat I called the menu in Appearance → Menus.

Comment: Do you have a set static page set as your home page?

Comment: "but gives me this error: `Error 404 - Not Found`" - this is a *non-sequitur* from the first part of your question. **What action, *specifically*,** gives you a `Error 404 - Not Found`.

Comment: You can also achieve it using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-home-page-menu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a home link to menus that you create via the menus admin area:

1. go to the **Pages** box,
2. click the 'View All' tab
3. 'Home' will appear, check the box and click 'add to menu'

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest this. Adding `$args['show_home'] = true;` to `page_menu_args` does two things: **1)** Displays a "Home" link in the default `wp_page_menu()` fallback for `wp_nav_menu()`, and **2)** adds a "Home" page option to the *Pages* meta box in `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus`, thereby allowing the user to add the "Home" page link to a custom menu.

Comment: @ChipBennett the 'Home' checkbox is always there in the view all tab regardless of any other settings in the theme. I've all always found it there without setting `$args['show_home']`. Have you observed a different behaviour in WP or have I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 1):

If you programmatically want to add the HOME menu item in the main menu (primary) then you can do with the following code.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'maple_custom_menu_filter', 10, 2 );
function maple_custom_menu_filter( $items, $args ) {
    /**
     * If menu primary menu is set.
     */
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {        

        $home = '<li class="menu-item"><a href="' . esc_url( get_home_url( '/' ) ) . '" title="'.esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ).'">Home</a></li>';
        $items = $home . $items;
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: much better response, since adding the menu item directly in the WP Menus could be problematic if we try to move theme to a new host; working on a dev site; etc